# Why does React TestingLibrary fail to render DOM node when wrapped in MemoryRouter?

Tags: react-router, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test a component that uses a `Router`, so I need to wrap my component in a `Router` component ( in this case, `MemoryRouter`). However, I've found that React TestingLibrary will not render DOM nodes when wrapped in a `Router`.

Dependencies:

- "react-router-dom": "4.3.1"
- "@testing-library/react": "9.1.3"

What I've tried:

1. (Works) Render a regular DOM node.

```
render(<div>TestTest</div>)

// Output
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      TestTest
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

2. Wrap the DOM node in `<MemoryRouter>`.

```
render(<MemoryRouter><div>TestTest</div></MemoryRouter>)

// Output
<body>
  <div />
</body>
```

3. Wrap the DOM node in `<MemoryRouter>` with `wrapper` option as specified in the [React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router) documentation.

```
render(<div>TestTest</div>, { wrapper: MemoryRouter })

// Output
<body>
  <div />
</body>
```

Comment: I figured this out, and it is specific to our project. It turned out we had mocked the `react-router-dom` module in our jest config.